# Keyboard Shortcut for Notification Center not working

Tags: macos, keyboard

The keyboard shortcut "Show Notification Center" you can set under *System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Mission Control* stopped working for me after a restart.

I tried resetting to defaults, changing the short cut and finally exiting all running apps and processes - nothing seems to bring back the short cut.

Does anybody know how to debug this or a plist where I can manually edit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting PRAM worked: https://discussions.apple.com/message/19284693?ac_cid=ms123456#19284693

Answer (score 1):

Resetting PRAM does not solve the issue for everyone (including another poster in the above thread, and myself).

I worked around it locally by using the MacOS Automator to create a new Workflow. The workflow had a single "Run Applescript" action in it where the applescript is as follows:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Notification Center"
            click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell    
end run
```

Then I saved the workflow and used BetterTouchTool (http://www.boastr.de/) to bind a "Start Automator Workflow" trigger to a a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting PRAM didn't work for me either. Chris Kline's solution is great, but I don't think the AppleScript is compatible with Mavericks or Yosemite.

This AppleScript works in Yosemite:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "SystemUIServer"
end tell
```

BetterTouchTool, as Chris mentioned, or Alfred (http://www.alfredapp.com/) can be used to assign a hotkey to the script.